# Map should be centered to a point and the nearest marker should be visible

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

At the initialization of my map, fitBounds is called, so that all the markers are visible. If a user allows to track his location the map centers to his location and zooms so it can happen that no markers are visible to him.

If a user allows to track his location, the map should center to his location, but the zoom needs to be adjusted that the nearest marker is visible.

```
var myPoint = new google.maps.LatLng(35.158868, -91.419260);
var myBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
var myOriginPoint = new google.maps.LatLng(33.126255, -89.531347);
myBounds.extend(myPoint);
myBounds.extend(myOriginPoint);
map.fitBounds(myBounds);
```

This will center my map between `myPoint` and `myOriginPoint`, but the center should be `myOriginPoint` and the marker at `myPoint` should also be visible.  I could calculate a LatLng that is the same distance as `myPoint` and goes in the other direction of `myOriginPoint`. But does anybody have a better idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
        html, body, #map {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px
        }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&amp;libraries=geometry"></script>
    <script>
        function initialize() {
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
              center: {lat: 0, lng: 0},
              zoom: 15,
              mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            });

            var myPoint = new google.maps.LatLng(51.514274, 7.467514);
            var myOriginPoint = new google.maps.LatLng(50.132168, 8.737313);

            var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myPoint,
                icon: 'http://maps.google.co.uk/intl/en_ALL/mapfiles/ms/micons/red.png',
                map: map
            });
            var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myOriginPoint,
                icon: 'http://maps.google.co.uk/intl/en_ALL/mapfiles/ms/micons/green-dot.png',
                map: map
            });

            var distance = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(myPoint, myOriginPoint);
            var heading = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeHeading(myPoint, myOriginPoint);
            var pointB = myOriginPoint.destinationPoint(heading, distance / 1000);

            var myBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
            myBounds.extend(myPoint);
            myBounds.extend(myOriginPoint);
            myBounds.extend(pointB);
            map.fitBounds(myBounds);

            map.fitBounds(myBounds);
        }

        Number.prototype.toRad = function() {
            return this * Math.PI / 180;
        }

        Number.prototype.toDeg = function() {
            return this * 180 / Math.PI;
        }

        google.maps.LatLng.prototype.destinationPoint = function(brng, dist) {
            dist = dist / 6371;  
            brng = brng.toRad();  

            var lat1 = this.lat().toRad(), lon1 = this.lng().toRad();

            var lat2 = Math.asin(Math.sin(lat1) * Math.cos(dist) + 
                                Math.cos(lat1) * Math.sin(dist) * Math.cos(brng));

            var lon2 = lon1 + Math.atan2(Math.sin(brng) * Math.sin(dist) *
                                        Math.cos(lat1), 
                                        Math.cos(dist) - Math.sin(lat1) *
                                        Math.sin(lat2));

            if (isNaN(lat2) || isNaN(lon2)) return null;

            return new google.maps.LatLng(lat2.toDeg(), lon2.toDeg());
        }

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

A point is calculated that is the same distance and direction as `myPoint`  to `myOriginPoint`. Compared to duncan's answer, the zoom is bigger.

[image: mine]

[image: duncan's]

Answer (score 0):

This seemed to work for me.
Calculate the distance in a straight line between your two points.
Let that be the radius for a circle, centred on `myOriginPoint`.
Find out the circle's bounds.
Extend your bounds to fit those bounds.

Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
        html, body, #map {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px
        }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&amp;libraries=geometry"></script>
    <script>
        function initialize() {
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
              center: {lat: 0, lng: 0},
              zoom: 3,
              mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            });

            var myPoint = new google.maps.LatLng(35.158868, -91.419260);
            var myOriginPoint = new google.maps.LatLng(33.126255, -89.531347);

            var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myPoint,
                icon: 'http://maps.google.co.uk/intl/en_ALL/mapfiles/ms/micons/red.png',
                map: map
            });
            var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myOriginPoint,
                icon: 'http://maps.google.co.uk/intl/en_ALL/mapfiles/ms/micons/green-dot.png',
                map: map
            });

            var distance = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(myPoint, myOriginPoint);

            var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
                fillColor: "#009900",
                fillOpacity: 0.25,
                strokeColor: "#00FF00",
                strokeOpacity: 1.0,
                strokeWeight: 1,
                center: myOriginPoint,
                radius: distance,
                map: map
            });

            var myBounds = circle.getBounds();

            map.fitBounds(myBounds);
        }

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's a screenshot demonstrating:

[image]

All you'd need to do is set the fillOpacity and strokeOpacity to zero to prevent this circle being visible.

Comment: The zoom was too small at some locations, so I've tried a different approach which gives a bigger zoom. Check out my answer.